# Compile glossary files individually for testing

Tags: glossaries, standalone, subfiles, import, multiple-files

Is there a setup that allows importing glossary definitions from another file, while at the same time being able to compile this file in a standalone manner (for testing purposes)?

`acronyms.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
\newacronym{relu}{ReLU}{Rectified Linear Unit}

\glsaddall[types=acronym]

\begin{document}
% we want to test compiling this single glossary in a standalone manner.
\printglossary[type=acronym, title=List of Acronyms, toctitle=List of Acronyms]
\end{document}
```

`main.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}

\import{glossaries/}{acronyms.tex}
\import{glossaries/}{symbols.tex}
\import{glossaries/}{units.tex}

\AtDocumentEnd{
   \backmatter
   \printglossaries
   \printindex
   \printbliography
}

...
```

I know there are several possible workarounds, like separating the `acronyms.tex` into two files `acronyms.sty`  and `test_acronyms.tex`, but I was wondering if there is an elegant solution with a single external file.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument` instead of `\AtDocumentEnd` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `standalone` package. It strips all contents before `\begin{document}` in subfiles.

`acronyms.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{standalone}
\standalonetrue

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
\newacronym{relu}{ReLU}{Rectified Linear Unit}
\glsaddall[types=acronym]

% we want to test compiling this single glossary in a standalone manner.
\ifstandalone
  \printglossary[type=acronym, title=List of Acronyms, toctitle=List of Acronyms]
\fi
\end{document}
```

I moved all definitions after `\begin{document}`, so they're read when `acronyms.tex` is a subfile. When compiled alone, the switch `\ifstandalone` is manually set to true.

`main.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\AtEndDocument{
   \backmatter
   \printglossaries
}

\begin{document}

\import{glossaries/}{acronyms.tex}

\end{document}
```

You must also load the package `glossaries` (only one preamble). The switch `\ifstandalone` is manually set to false.